# The MSI installer of Python crashes (Windows Installer problems)

Tags: python, windows, windows-xp

My system is Windows XP 32 bit and I have a working installation of Python 2.7 installed. 
I would to update to version 2.7.3, but, unfortunately, when I launch the installer, it crashes. I am able to click Next in the first dialog, selecting to install it for All Users, but after this, a window appears saying that the Windows Installer has encountered a problem and it will be closed.

I have also tried with the Python 3.3 installer but the problem is the same :-(

I have tried to log the operation but I am not able to understand what fails. The log is [here](http://pastebin.com/R9KWsAj6).

The log is of the Python 3.3 installation (the Python 2.7 log was longer). I see some errors but it seems me that the installer passes through these errors. I don't see what's failing.

Sandro